# Write spark dataframe from databricks onto the azure data lack store using R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to save/write/upload a spark dataframe from databricks onto the azure data lack store folder using R. I found the following python code.

```
spark_df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save('...path to azure data lake store folder')
```

Can you suggest me a SparkR equivalent of this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
spark_df %>% 
  coalesce(1L) %>%          # Same as coalesce(1).
  write.df(                 # Generic writer, because there is no csv specific one
    "...path to azure...",  # Path as before 
     source = "csv",        # Since 2.0 you don't need com.databricks 
     mode = "overwrite", 
     header = "true"        # All ... are used as options
  )
```